# DDD Execution Windows never opens, loads infinitely

Tags: assembly, x86, ddd-debugger

thanks everyone for all the help before.

This time, I needed the Execution Window in order to see what the code is doing, but it doesn't open. Trying to open it gives me the dialog box you see below, and it simply never opens. I'm running the Ubuntu app on my Windows 10 laptop, utilizing the Linux Subsystem. DDD opens with VcXsrv that I downloaded in order to display the debugger. I'm not sure what's wrong, haven't seen this issue anywhere else when I search for it. Is it an issue with VcXsrv? It can display multiple windows from what I've seen (opening several DDD debuggers).

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I was being mentally incapable. Linux isn't my strong suit, I needed to install xterm apparently:

sudo apt-get install xterm

That solved the issue.

Comment: That's amusing.  DDD is pretty old, I guess nobody ever bothered to implement an error check in the debugger to detect that spawning an `xterm` can fail!  (Traditional Linux systems always used to have xterm installed; it's fairly recent that distros make it optional, long after it stopped being the default terminal emulator for some desktops.  e.g. gnome-terminal and konsole are often used instead.)

Comment: The Ubuntu app for Windows with the Linux Subsystem is very bare bones so it doesn't come with a lot of things. I also found it odd that it was trying to open something that didn't exist and that there was no error, so I never suspected that I needed to download another package!

Comment: Oh, modern GNU/Linux distros don't always install `xterm` these days; it's not just WSL Ubuntu.